# how to show multiple markers in map from sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps-markers

m getting different users latLng as a json object and m storing and updating it in sqlite with that user name , now i want to retrive that lacations of users and show these users in to map.. and update their location as message arrived af that user... how to do that

this is my code

```
                    JSONObject  jsnobject = new JSONObject(Message);
                     JSONObject msg = jsnobject.getJSONObject("msg");

                     JSONObject header = msg.getJSONObject("Header"); 
                      clientID=header.getString("from");


                     JSONObject location = header.getJSONObject("Location"); 
                     LAT = location.getString("Lat");
                      LNG = location.getString("Long");
                      SPEED = location.getString("Speed");

                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }






                //   for(int i =0 ;i<abc;i++){


                    List<String> a= db.getID();

                    if(a.contains(clientID)){

                        db.update(clientID, LAT, LNG, SPEED);
                    }else{

                        db.insert(clientID, LAT, LNG, SPEED);

                    }
```

and this is how m placing the marker

```
                 List<String> a= db.getID();

                 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){ 



                        String id=a.get(i);

                    List<String> latllng= db.getLatLng(id);
                    latllng.toString();
                    String[] Latlng=latllng.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(Latlng[0]);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(Latlng[1]);
                    googleMap.clear();   


                    if (marker == null)
                    pos=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            pos, 17));
                    marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(pos));
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker));
                    marker.setTitle(id);
                    pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    animateMarker(marker, pos, hideMarker);

                 }
```

Comment: pls tell me how to do after storing the data in sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like this and it will work:

```
    List<String> a = db.getID();
    googleMap.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

            String id = a.get(i);

            List<String> latllng = db.getLatLng(id);
            latllng.toString();
            String[] Latlng = latllng.toString().replace("[", "")
                    .replace("]", "").split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(Latlng[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(Latlng[1]);
            // googleMap.clear(); <<< comment out this code else all of your previous marker get cleared

            if (marker == null)
                pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
             // googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 17)); << you can not move map for each and every marker you are adding
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos));
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker));
            marker.setTitle(id);
            pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            animateMarker(marker, pos, hideMarker); 

        }
```

Comment: ok dont go anywhere let me check i m working on it ritenow..wait.. :)

Comment: how can i animate it??

Comment: you can animate any one value. now you have to decide which value you want to animate first, last or middle. extract specific value from your location list and pass it to animate method

Comment: another way is to animate on the basis of your current location but there may be the possibility that your current location is different and list of location you are having is different

Comment: sruu but i didnt get it.. :(

Comment: i need to show every user location with smooth moving marker

Comment: if (pos == a.size()){
  animateMarker(marker, pos, hideMarker); 
  }    error is ()pos==a.size()) "Incompatible operand types LatLng and int   "

Comment: single user is moving well but when other comes in the animation collapsed